Question about Hebrew translations of Leviticus 23:15
Why do modern translations of the Hebrew Bible translate the plural Sabbaths in Leviticus 23:15 with a singular Sabbath? All English translations of this verse on Bible Gateway translate it as singular, yet it is in the plural in the Hebrew scriptures. Am I right?
טווּסְפַרְתֶּ֤ם לָכֶם֙ מִמָּֽחֳרַ֣ת הַשַּׁבָּ֔ת מִיּוֹם֙ הֲבִ֣יאֲכֶ֔ם אֶת־עֹ֖מֶר הַתְּנוּפָ֑ה שֶׁ֥בַע שַׁבָּת֖וֹת תְּמִימֹ֥ת תִּֽהְיֶֽינָה
In the Bible Hub website, a respected website for Christian Bible Study, they translate the word Sabbath in Leviticus 23:15 with a plural rendering in the interlinear. The word is  שַׁבָּת֖וֹת
Is that word really a plural, or did Bible Hub make a mistake?
Thanks

הַשַּׁבָּ֔ת is singular, שֶׁ֥בַע שַׁבָּת֖וֹת is seven Sabbaths, plural. Everything is quite ordinary.

The word appears twice in Leviticus 23:15:

The first instance is הַשַּׁבָּת (ha-shabat, the sabbath, singular).
The second is שַׁבָּתוֹת (shabatoth, sabbaths, plural).

What is an example of an incorrect translation of the verse, which instance are you asking about, and why do you think it is incorrect?

I have had discussions with a fellow from this forum and another that we are in and he believes that Sabbath is plural in the Hebrew in this verse. It CAN be because at the Bible Hub website they have an interlinear and in Leviticus 23:15 it identifies the word Sabbath as plural. In the NASB 1995 edition the expression "the Sabbath" appears 51 times in the Old Testament. 48 of them are singular, twice it is not found in the interlinear, and once as a Sabbath and that is -- you guessed it--Leviticus 23:15.

Maybe the interlinear is in error. I don't know. With lack of further evidence, I must admit that Leviticus 23:15 CAN be plural I just can't say for sure. I suspect a scribe altered the text to turn the singular Sabbath into Sabbaths. I have high confidence in most scribes, as they were honest and conscientious. But I believe there were some willing to tamper with the text. A scribe, who adhered to the rabbinical tradition, could easliy have changed Leviticus 23:15 from a singular to a plural because in the LXX Leviticus 23:15 translated it as a plural.

Or, maybe, the person in charge of designating singulars and plurals in the interlinear made a mistake. The JPS 1917 and 1985 both render the Tanach with a singular Sabbath in Lev. 23:15.

Thanks for your informative answer.

+1 As you can see here https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62640/can-nisan-15-be-referred-to-as-the-sabbath/70783#70783 my understanding of the Hebrew is exactly as this answer states. Not only is it singular, but the article makes it emphatically so, the Sabbath. I suspect the OP is confusing how the LXX translates the Hebrew, τῆς ἐπαύριον τῶν σαββάτων, the next day of the Sabbaths.

No, the Hebrew word in the Bible Hub interlinear in Leviticus 23:15 is שַׁבָּת֖וֹת

@SaberTruthTiger says "the Hebrew word in the Bible Hub interlinear in Leviticus 23:15 is שַׁבָּת֖וֹת".  Right, but that's the word that's part of "seven sabbaths", so why would you think it shouldn't be plural?

Read the interlinear in Bible Hub. Leviticus 23:15 the first Sabbath in the verse is plural. They may have mistakenly used the plural noun instead of the singular noun. https://biblehub.com/leviticus/23-15.htm The plural second Sabbath is translated as weeks.

@SaberTruthTiger. — Leviticus 23:15 Interlinear says: "7676 [e] // haš·šab·bāṯ, // הַשַּבָּת // the after Sabbath // Art | N‑cs", with the last line meaning "Article:: Noun - common singular".
Why do you say it is plural?

I have updated my post on Christian Forums to reflect this. Thank You so much for finding this. My page with the interlinear calls it a plural but yours calls it a singular. I  have given you credit on my post in Christian Forums.

Here's the link that shows the plural Sabbath on Bible Hub:    https://biblehub.com/leviticus/23-15.htm

@SaberTruthTiger I think we are all confused on your approach. The word appears twice in Leviticus 23. The first is singular, and shows as such on Bible Hub's Interlinear and the second is plural and shown as such. https://biblehub.com/interlinear/leviticus/23-15.htm The meanings are straight forward. הַשַּׁבָּ֔ת is the singular Sabbath. שַׁבָּת֖וֹת is plural as it speaks to having counted seven complete Sabbaths.

I was the one who was confused. I have a lot of confidence in the Bible Hub interlinear. Then, I discovered they used the first sabbath in Leviticus 23:15 as plural. I am glad Ray pointed out the error, but it was done because I did not check the other interlinear on Bible Hub. Just check this link, scroll to the bottom and see that the interlinear does give the singular a plural rating.  https://biblehub.com/leviticus/23-15.htm

@RevelationLad, Right at the bottom of the linked page, it really does have the singular (the sabbath) and plural (sabbaths or weeks) instances switched.
